# Finding the dual problem with exponential equation

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, convex-optimization, duality-theorems, programming

I need to find the dual problem of this:

[image]

but I have no idea how to work with the norm or the exponential function

Comment: Hint: the exponential function is monotonic.

Comment: The constraint $\|x\| \le x_1$ means that $x_2 = 0$.

Comment: Yeah I found that but how do I write the dual problem

Comment: Thank you for the reply though